# Как сделать что бы при открытии http://www.site.ru/flowers%2Flilac был редирект на http://www.site.ru/flowers/lilac

Tags: php, cms, opencart

Как сделать, чтобы при открытии `http://www.site.ru/flowers%2Flilac` был редирект на `http://www.site.ru/flowers/lilac`?

Comment: Яндекс Директ требует

Comment: нужно как-то в .htaccess сделать редирект так как flowers и lilac это параметры (могут быть ключи)

Comment: Читайте ответы тут https://stackoverflow.com/q/4390436/5441700 и тут https://stackoverflow.com/q/25745832/5441700

Answer (score 1):

Можно сделать через `.htaccess`. Например, командой `Redirect`:

```
Redirect 301 /old/old.htm http://www.you.ru/new.htm
```

Или через директивы `mod_rewrite`:

```
RewriteRule ^cat/oldpage.* /newpage.html [R=301,L]
```

Подробнее можно почитать в [этой статье](https://zarabotat-na-sajte.ru/seo/htaccess-redirekt-i-opisanie.html).

Только нужно учитывать, что редирект подразумевает определённые коды ответа сервера и их влияние в плане SEO.

Answer (score -1):

Попробуйте ето
`header(' http://www.site.ru/flowers/lilac');`

Удачи

Comment: нужно как-то в .htaccess сделать редирект так как flowers и lilac это параметры

Comment: Но через php тоже можно, просто проверять по параметрам и генерировать строку.
Не рекомендую использовать .htaccess вещь странная местами опасная + некоторые хостинги запрещают изменять етот файл

Comment: такой вариант не подходит